# How to share filtered image in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an image processing windows 10 application. I am applying filters on that image and showing it on the image element. This is how I am applyting filter and setting it as a source to MainImage element.

```
 ProcessImage processImage = new ProcessImage(sourcePixels, width, height);

       byte[] blurEffect = processImage.BlurEffect(width, height);

        WriteableBitmap blurImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
        using (Stream stream = blurImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(blurEffect, 0, blurEffect.Length);
            MainImage.Source = blurImage;
        }
```

Up till now I have set the WriteableBitmap image to the source. Now I want to share this image using DataTransferManager's Data requested event as shown

```
 dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        dataTransferManager.DataRequested += DataTransferManager_DataRequested;
```

The body of its event containing this code

```
 DataPackage dataPackage = args.Request.Data;
        dataPackage.Properties.Title = "App Name";
        dataPackage.Properties.Description = "My description";

        dataPackage.SetBitmap();
```

On the share button click event, i am calling showshareUI like this

```
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

I am trying to share image using fourth line above that is SetBitmap method, but the problem here is this method want **RandomAccessStreamReference** value and I have a filtered image of type writeablebitmap. How can I get this thing done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your WriteableBitmap to an [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx)

I don't have access to my dev machine so I can't test it but here's a quick sample:

```
private async Task<IRandomAccessStream> Convert(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
    {
        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
        Stream pixelStream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
        await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();

        return stream;
    }
```

Since `dataPackage.SetBitmap()` expects a `RandomAccessStreamReference` object you will need to obtain one based on the `IRandomAccessStream` that the above method returns. Fortunately that is pretty easy:

```
var streamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream)
```

Hope that works.

Comment: After receiving back the stream and setting it to dataPackage.SetBitmap(stream); it is showing an error that "Can't convert from System.Threading.Tasks.Task<...> to Window.Storage.Streams.MemoryAccessStreamReferece

Comment: make sure you await the method when you call it. i.e. stream = await Convert(...)

Comment: Ya, done that, now as i pass the result in dataPackage.SetBitmap(result); it says can't convert from IRandomAccessStream to RandomAccessStreamReference.