# Share Images in UWP Windows 10 Apps

Tags: c#, uwp

I am applying filters on the image and as a result I am getting an object of `WriteableBitmap` as shown

```
byte[] effect = ApplyEffect(width, height);

WriteableBitmap resultImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
using (Stream stream = resultImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(effect, 0, effect.Length);
    MyImage.Source = resultImage;
}
```

I want to share this resultImage using `DataTransferManager`. After making event handle of DataTransferManager, inside that event handle I am trying to share image with the help of `SetBitmap` method.

```
 DataPackage dataPackage = args.Request.Data;
 dataPackage.Properties.Description = "Description";
 dataPackage.Properties.Title = "Name";

 // setBitmap need object of RandomAccessStreamReference
 dataPackage.SetBitmap();
```

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732360/how-to-share-filtered-image-in-uwp-c-sharp) thread, I have converted my `WriteableBitmap` result image to `IRandomAccessStream`, but still I am unable to pass value inside `SetBitmap` method, as it shows error.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error, you need to obtain a `RandomAccessStreamReference` from your `IRandomAccessStream` to pass on to the `dataPackage.SetBitmap` method.

```
var str = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(randomAccessStream);
dataPackage.SetBitmap(str);
```

Comment: As I click on share button, it says there was a problem with the data from "App_Name"

Comment: I am doing it like this var stream = await Convert(result_Image);
                var str = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream);
                dataPackage.SetBitmap(str);